# R - convert numeric to percentage and geom_col

Tags: r

Can someone help me with the following?

my data frame looks like below:

```
tibble::tribble(
  
  ~date,         ~ratio_type,   ~percentage,
  "30/06/2016",  "gp",          0.25,
  "30/06/2016",  "EBIT",        0.20,
  "30/06/2017",  "gp",          0.30,
  "30/06/2017",  "EBIT",        0.18,
)
```

It reads date as date, ratio_type as character, and percentage as numeric.

I have two problems:

1. How to convert numeric value to percentage in R
2. In my plot(geom_col) I mapped date in the x axis and percentage in the y axis. I need separate columns for each ratio_type for the year. However, in my column chart, I get only one column for each year and ratio_type's are stacked in one column. How do I get separate columns for each ratio type for each year?

Answer (score 1):

1.`scale::label_percent()` convert numeric value to percentage in `R`

2.`position = position_dodge()` will separate columns and `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` will make y axis percentage.

```
df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y= percentage, group = ratio_type, fill = ratio_type)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]